# EditText is not editable in Fragment

Tags: android

I don't know why is this happening.. In other activities EditText is working fine. This is how my fragment layout looks:

```
    <EditText
        android:gravity="center"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/profile_image"
        android:text="Dusan Dimitrijevic"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:id="@+id/et_username"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Is something affecting in layout these EditTexts so they can't be editable. If i need to show you Java code, let me know. I can set text to EditText by the way, but can't edit it..

Comment: Too much code. Post only the guilty `EditText`.

Comment: Well i have post the whole layout because i don't know, maybe some other view is causing edittext to be not editable..

Comment: Before the edit, I would have guessed that you have some overlapping view that is consuming the onTouch event

Comment: @Dusan Dimitrijevic Do you run your app in emulator or on real device?

Comment: On real device, but it's the same case also with the emulator. I have tried using EditText in another fragment and it was not working.

Comment: @Dusan Dimitrijevic do it like this: editText.setEditable(true);

Comment: There is no issue with your edittext, may be some other view causing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `background` and the `text`. Use `hint` instead of `text`

```
<EditText
    android:gravity="center"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:hint="Dusan Dimitrijevic"
    android:layout_below="@+id/profile_image"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:id="@+id/et_username"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Comment: I put that in my layout and the `EditText` was not looking like its editable. Though it was editable. :D

Comment: Do you run your app in emulator or on real device?

Comment: I ran it in an emulator. But of course, it'll do the same in real device.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this and resolved by identifying an overlapping layout/element declared below **editText** thus preventing interaction with the **editText** element. My **editText** element envelop (parent) layout had the same:

```
android:layout_below="@+id/xxxxxx"
```

specification as the layout below it.